# Import error for Material3 in Jetpack Compose Android Project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am building an Android app and am using Material3 Theme Builder. I am able to export my custom theme as a zip with Theme.kt. I add it to my folder and made sure to update my package name because Theme.kt defaults to com.example.ui.Theme . I am running into some import issues with material3. Here is the imports in my header.

```
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.lightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
```

I also tried to add the latest version of `com.google.android.material.material 1.8.0-alpha01`

into my gradle file but it breaks some other imports in some of my other files like

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Shapes
```

Before I changed anything in my gradle file my implementation line looked like this.
`implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"`
I am compiling on SDK 32 and the newest version of Gradle and Android Studio Dolphin. Any suggestions on what I could do to properly import material3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Compose M3 you should add this dependency in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$material3_version"
```

Currently the latest version is `1.0.0-beta03`.

Then you have to import the classes in the `material3` package, for example:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.lightColorScheme
```

Finally:

```
com.google.android.material.material 1.8.0-alpha01
```

This dependency is the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and it is not related to Compose.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-beta03"
```

I added these to my build.gradle file.